# Short int values above 32767

Tags: c, short

When trying to store short integer values above 32,767 in C, just to see what happens, I notice the result that gets printed to the screen is the number I am trying to store, -  65,536. E.g. if i try to store 65,536 in a short variable, the number which is printed to the screen is 0. If I try to store 32,768 I get **-32,768** printed to the screen. And if I try to store 65,546 and print it to the screen I get 10. I think you get the picture. Why am I seeing these results?

Comment: A short is 2 bytes (usually, it depends). 2 bytes = 16 bits. The first one is sign, so you can store values up to 2^15 before it rolls over and becomes negative.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%27s_complement

Comment: (it's actually undefined behaviour for signed types, although I've never known an implementation to do anything other than modulo the value)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Integer values are stored using [Twos Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement). In twos complement, the range of possible values is `-2^n` to `2^n-1`, where n is the number of bits used for storage. Because of the way the storage is done, when you go above `2^n-1`, you end up wrapping around back to `2^n`.

Shorts use **16 bits** (15 bits for numeric storage, with the final bit being the sign).

EDIT: Keep in mind that this behavior is NOT guaranteed to occur. Programming languages may act completely differently. Technically, going above or below the max/min value is undefined behavior and it should be treated as such. (Thanks to Eric Postpischil for keeping me on my toes)

Comment: The behavior is undefined. You cannot rely on two’s complement. Even if the underlying hardware uses two’s complement, optimization in the compiler can result code containing an overflow being omitted or changed in surprising ways.

Comment: That is correct, but the reason he is seeing what he is seeing is the underlying Twos Complement not being abstracted or optimized away. Definitely not behavior to rely upon, but behavior that can be explained.

Comment: Then the answer should explicitly state that. Keep in mind that this answer is durable and may be seen by many other people seeking to understand similar issues. Stating without qualification that integer values are stored using two’s complement is false and, even when it is true in the underlying hardware, it is misleading because language rules do not require overflow in the C language to produce the same behavior as overflow in two’s complement.

Answer (score 1):

When a value is converted to a signed integer type but cannot be represented in that type, overflow occurs, and the behavior is undefined. It is common to see results as if a two’s complement encoding is used and as if the low bits are stored (or, equivalently, the value is wrapped modulo an appropriate power of two). However, you cannot rely on this behavior. The C standard says that, when signed integer overflow occurs, the behavior is undefined. So a compiler may act in surprising ways.

Consider this code, compiled for a target where `short int` is 16 bits:

```
void foo(int a, int b)
{
    if (a)
    {
        short int x = b;
        printf("x is %hd.\n", x);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("x is not assigned.\n");
    }
}

void bar(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 65536)
        foo(a, b);
}
```

Observe that `foo` is a perfectly fine function on its own, provided `b` is within range of a `short int`. And `bar` is a perfectly fine function, as long as it is called only with `a` equal to zero or `b` not equal to 65536.

While the compiler is in-lining `foo` in `bar`, it may deduce from the fact that `b` must be 65536 at this point, that there would be an overflow in `short int x = b;`. This implies either that this path is never taken (i.e., `a` must be zero) or that any behavior is permitted (because the behavior upon overflow is undefined by the C standard). In either case, the compiler is free to omit this code path. Thus, for optimization, the compiler could omit this path and generate code only for `printf("x is not assigned.\n");`. If you then executed code containing `bar(1, 65536)`, the output would be “x is not assigned.”!

Compilers do make optimizations of this sort: The observation that one code path has undefined behavior implies the compiler may conclude that code path is never used.

To an observer, it looks like the effect of assigning a too-large value to a `short int` is to cause completely different code to be executed.